# webViewDidFinishLoad not calling when having javascript content in webpage

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm using `UIWebView` in a project. Sometimes it doesn't call the `webViewDidFinishLoad` method. Because the web page have some javascripts. The method

```
- (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType
```

is getting call but `webViewDidFinishLoad` doesn't. I want to catch that method. Because I'm start an animation when the webview start loading. Then I want to stop this animation when it finished. It's not working with websites having javascript content. Any one have an idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`webViewDidFinishLoad` method gets called when the `UIWebView` has finished loading the url, in your case since you are calling a `javascript`, it doesn't load your content, it just calls a `javascript` function in your already loaded `webview`. But `YES` you can catch the javascript actions in the same method you stated as below

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){

          if([url rangeOfString:@"SOMETHING"].length > 0 ){ 
             //if your action returns something appended in your url like the anchors work

                     //DO YOUR STUFFS       
          }
    }

    return TRUE;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the webview in ios checks specifically for "iframe" tags in the html's dom and in case it finds, it creates events based on that tag as well. therefore, a simple however a patchy solution would be adding the following code in the part of the dom that is changing (for example, in the actual template of each section):

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

did the trick for me..